# In Scala, how can I get the max date from an array of maps where one of the keys in the map is "date"?

Tags: arrays, scala, scala-collections

I have an array of maps and the maps and I would like to find the maximum date in the array of maps and I think I'm heading down a non-scala path because I'm not sure how to wire the pieces of this question together.

Is there a better way of doing this? I'm concerned that I need to assume things like casting the value to a Date for comparison, but that is what's in the Map and the map includes other data types also (so Map[String, Object] is what I have)

```
val df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")     
def omap = List(Map("date" -> df.parse("2013-08-01")), Map("date" -> df.parse("2013-02-01"), "otherkey" -> "nothing special"), Map("date" -> df.parse("2013-01-01")))
omap.max(new Ordering[Map[String, Object]] {
  def compare(x: Map[String, Object], y: Map[String, Object]) = x.get("date").get.asInstanceOf[Date] compareTo y.get("date").get.asInstanceOf[Date]
})
```

The code seems to work, but I feel like I'm missing a more scala like way of doing this.

Comment: I'm not sure why @senia has a downvote, but `maxBy` seems like the right solution. I'd do `maxBy(_("date").asInstanceOf[Date])` but it's roughly the same thing. Stepping back a bit, having a map of `String` to `Object` feels bad. If you have structured objects that are guaranteed to always contain a field, use language features to say that or you'll run into bugs and aren't using your tools to their full potential. One solution might be to make a `case class` that has a `date` field of the right type, instead of a map with an untyped string mapping.

Answer (score 2):

This little one liner works, but it will throw an exception if there is no date in any map:

```
omap.flatMap(map => map.get("date").collect({case d:Date => d})).max
```

Here's a safer version, but you have to provide a default date:

```
  val defaultDate = new Date()
  omap.map(map => map.get("date").collect({case d:Date => d}))
    .foldLeft(defaultDate)((default, od) => od.fold(default)( d => if (d.compareTo(default) > 0) d else default))
```

Comment: `map{...}.flattem` === `flatMap`. Any way: do not make things complicated. There is `"date"`in every map.

Comment: Maybe there isn't one in every map, we have no guarantee at compile time. Good call on the `flatMap`.

Answer (score 0):

```
omap.maxBy{ _("date").asInstanceOf[Date] }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a minimal number of types, you should probably make them explicit with something like `Either`.  But I'll assume you have too many for that.

Then, the more canonical way to get your value is something like this (to replace your `omap.max`):

```
val defaultDate = df.parse("1970-01-01")

def dateFrom(m: Map[String, Object]) =
  m.get("date").collect{ case d: Date => d }.getOrElse(defaultDate)

omap.maxBy(dateFrom)
```

This protects you from missing entries by grouping everything missing into the earliest possible date.

If you don't have any sensible default date, then

```
def dateFrom(m: Map[String, Object]) = m.get("date").collect{ case d: Date => d }
omap.max(new Ordering[Map[String, Object]] {
  def compare(x: Map[String, Object], y: Map[String, Object]) = {
    (dateFrom(x), dateFrom(y)) match {
      case (Some(a), Some(b)) => a compareTo b
      case (_, None) => -1
      case _         => 1
    }
  }
})
```

to shuffle all dateless maps to the end.

Comment: There is `"date"` element in every map. And even if there are maps without `"date"` `1970-01-01` is an anti-pattern. You'll get wrong behaviour even on birth dates (like `1960-01-01`). Exception is good: ease to find and easy to fix. Incorrect behaviour is bad. `0001-01-01` is not a solution: history data, astronomies data, etc.

Comment: @senia Exceptions are an anti pattern and hard to fix. Defining default behavior is good.

Comment: @Noah: it's not a default behaviour, it's an unexpected behaviour.